# Plotly data from nested for loop

Tags: javascript, c#, plotly

In c# codebehind I define a few Lists this way:

```
public List<string> divs = new List<string>();
public List<List<string>> names = new List<List<string>>();
public List<List<List<string>>> labels = new List<List<List<string>>>();
public List<List<List<double>>> longitude = new List<List<List<double>>>();
```

Quite large lists I know but I feel it's necessary for getting all my info from my source organized correctly.

in JS I serialize these like this:

```
var divArr = <%=new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(divs)%>;
var names = <%=new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(names)%>;
var lbl = <%=new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(labels)%>;
var long = <%=new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(longitude)%>;
```

And then I try to do a function to plot all this on separate graphs. 10 graphs in total on my page that can have several lines on all of them. Trying to make my page as dynamic as possible. So I have a function to loop through all of this and try to plot it all.

```
function doGraph(){
    for(index = 0; index < divArr.length; ++index){
        (function() {

            var data = [];
            for(indx = 0; indx < lbl[index].length; ++indx){
                var trace = {
                    name: names[index][indx],
                    x: lbl[index][indx],
                    y: long[index][indx],
                    mode:'lines'
                };
                data.push(trace);
            }

            var gd = document.getElementById(divArr[index]);
            plotly.newPlot(gd,data);

                })();
            }
}
```

And it ALMOST works. Every graph seems to plot the first set of data given to it but nothing afterwords. Maybe I've been staring at this too long but I just can't see what I'm doing wrong here but I'm sure it's something I've just over looked. Or maybe I'm overreaching and I can't do this sort of thing? Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: your javascript code confusing me and looks like wrong bracket-using. Additionally I don't understand the use of an inner function `(function(){` at line 3 - but im not a javascript pro. Furthermore I think you need a big P for `Plotly.newPlot(gd,data)`

Comment: @flipperweid You're right on the Plotly being capitalized. Missed that. I'm no javascript pro either but what I'm trying to do with the loop is make an array of trace data. var data is an array and each var trace is a trace object that i'm pushing into the array. Though I can't find specific examples like this for Plotly so I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly

Comment: @flipperweid I figured it out and added my answer below. The real problem turned out to be with my crazy lists and the serialization of them. Thanks for your input though I cleaned up my code.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out the problem was with the serialization from my lists to js arrays. Apparently js serialize can't quite handle the level of multidimensional list I was going crazy with. So I fixed it by making the lists one level less deep and made another list to keep track of how "deep" they are in this fashion:

C# Codebehind:

```
public List<List<string>> names = new List<List<string>>();
public List<int> numObjs = new List<int>();
public List<List<string>> labels = new List<List<string>>();
public List<List<double>> longitude = new List<List<double>>();
```

JS Serialization:

```
var divArr = <%=new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(divs)%>;
var names = <%=new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(names)%>;
var numO = <%=new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(numObjs)%>;
var lbl = <%=new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(labels)%>;
var long = <%=new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(longitude)%>;
```

Then the JS function has the real changes with a loop in this way:

```
function doGraph(){
        var cur = 0;
        for(var index = 0; index < divArr.length; ++index){
                var data = [];
                var top = cur + numO[index];
                for(var indx = cur; indx < top; ++indx){
                    data.push({
                        name: names[indx],
                        mode:'lines',
                        x: lbl[indx],
                        y: long[indx],
                    });
                    cur++;
                }

                var gd = document.getElementById(divArr[index]);
                Plotly.newPlot(gd, data, 
                                layout , {scrollZoom:true,modeBarButtonsToRemove:['sendDataToCloud'],showLink:false,displaylogo:false});
        }
}
```

Also my function within a function was definitely unnecessary as @flipperweid said.